# Why eating Rosh Hashan Simanim (signs) only in the evenings

Tags: minhag, rosh-hashanah-new-year, simanim

The minhag (custom) is to see or eat Rosh simanim at the both Rosh Hashana evenings. It is also found in the Gemara ( תלמוד בבלי, מסכת כריתות, דף ה', עמוד ב' – דף ו', עמוד א) that the main point is to see them and not necessarily to eat. So the question intensifies, why not eating the simanim also or instead at Rosh Hashana morning (and not at night), so it will be easier to recognize and see them?

Comment: Many people only do simanim on the first night.

Comment: According to some opinions, there is no obligation to have a meal by day on Rosh Hashanah

Comment: Heard a nice vort that Rosh Hashanah is all about crowning Gd as long and we do this during the daytime. But when, then, are we able to focus on the upcoming new year being good, and to focus on teshuva thoughts? This is in the nighttime, and is why we do the Simanim then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the night meal is the first opprotunity at the begining of the year and there would be no need to repeat it at day. (Those who repeat the Simanim at second night do this because of "Sfeika Dyoma"- maybe tonight is the first night.)

Comment: There is additional issue about it, since the Simanim has to be seen by Gemara, why is it done at night? Tzitzit is applicable only on the morning from the same reason.

Comment: Which Gemara states that the Simanim must be seen?

Comment: גמ' בהוריות (יב.): ""לעולם יהא רגיל למיחזי בריש שתא קרא רוביא כרתי וסילקא ותמרי", משמע שמספיק לראות הסימנים שנועדו לסימן טוב, וכן גירסת הערוך (ערך קרא) "למחזי", וכן כתוב בכלבו (סי' ס"ד), ובשיטה מקובצת (כריתות ו.) שיש גורסין למחזי. וכן כתב הב"י (סי' תקפ"ג) שזו גירסת הספרים.